# How do I change how long notifications are displayed?

Tags: notify-osd, libnotify

Is there a way to change how long the libnotify notifications last? I've googled around for this for months and no still no luck.

I'm actually starting to think that you can't change it. I can't even find anywhere in the API where developers can control this.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question as "How do I change how long notifications are displayed?"; "Notification Display Time" is pretty confusing, and not phrased as a question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this normally. However, there is a patched version of notify-osd that supports it:[image]

## From Ubuntu 16.04 onwards:

You'll need to add two PPA's:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
```

Then install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

The configuration dialog should be in Applications->Accessories or `notifyosdconf` from the terminal. There's a setting for the standard notification duration as per screenshot above if you don't set it the `--expire-time` parameter.

#### Example:

```
notify-send --urgency=LOW --expire-time=1 --icon=face-laugh "test" "1 second"
```

## Older versions: (9.10-14.10)

You'll need to add two PPA's:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

The configuration dialog should be in Applications->Accessories or `notifyosdconf` from the terminal. There's a setting for notification duration as per screenshot above.

#### Example:

```
notify-send --urgency=LOW --expire-time=1 --icon=face-laugh "test" "1 second"
```

Comment: those two ppa's are the same? after googling 'notifyosdconfig ppa' i think the second one you meant was `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig`

Comment: Just a note, though the above program works *beautifully*, you're still limited by a maximum time of 10 seconds. You can go *below* 10 seconds, but not above (which is what I was after when I started looking).

Comment: does this override the default `notify-send`  behaviour or is it a seperate command?

Comment: Unfortunately, the repository doesnt provide the package anymore, saying `E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: Got E: Unable to locate package notifyosdconfig

Answer (score 4):

crude but effective and then some - caveat this also kills pending notifications
this can only shorten display times just change the `1.5` in `sleep 1.5;` below:

ref:
details in [Close button on notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd/189956#189956)

x-ref:
[Expiry time in notify-send notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182723/expiry-time-in-notify-send-notifications)

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"            \
| grep --line-buffered  "member=Notify"                             \
| sed -u -e 's/.*/sleep 1.5; killall notify-osd/'                   \
| bash
```

Bookmarks:
self - [How do I change how long notifications are displayed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50/how-do-i-change-how-long-notifications-are-displayed/192674#192674)
[Expiry time in notify-send notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182723/expiry-time-in-notify-send-notifications/192673#192673)

Answer (score 3):

The duration of the notification is, I believe, dependent on the length of the message.

From the perspective of someone who was worked with it indirectly (by using the pynotify module in Python), I have discovered that specifying a duration for a message is not possible.