# Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?

Tags: notify-osd, libnotify

Is there any way to prevent NotifyOSD (or XFCE-Notify) from displaying notifications from one particular application?

Comment: I think it depends on the application rather than notification-daemon application like xchat or empathy give you the option of disabling notification.

Comment: Obviously I'm talking about an app that does not have this option...

Comment: which application are you talking about

Comment: I mean Jupiter, it has some problems with notifications - under XFCE-notify they do not close, under NotifyOSD they get reopened several times before they close. Still it would be nice to prevent any app from spamming those.

Comment: seems like the notification is just the script located at `/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/notify` just edit the script to do nothing

Comment: sadly my feeble attempts to modify this file resulted in losing the tray icon for Jupiter...

Comment: Well, as I went through all the scripts inside `/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/` I see a flag called No_NOTIFY. May be you should run jupiter with `-silent` argument or May be just change `if [ ! "$NO_NOTIFY" = "1" ];` to `if [ "$NO_NOTIFY" = "1" ];` But may be you have tried that already

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked! Stil, a pity we can't "blacklist" an app :)

Comment: @sagarchalise Answer this question below so it can be marked as answered please :)

Comment: @Borsook 'blacklisting' an application will not be an easy thing to do. There are thousands of ways so as to display a notification, like doing it directly, using a command that calls `notify-send`, or calling a completely external script. Tracking all these down so as to prevent notifications would be very hard to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes but with caveats ... `killall notify-osd` is aggressive ... to do this gracefully requires that pending notifications be saved before the offending one triggers `killall notify-osd` and then reinstate them preserving chronological integrity.

ref:
[Close button on notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd/189956#189956)
it would be nice if: [Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in)

Monitor `D-Bus` to find notifications for removal that originate from the chosen application. Run this script in a terminal or as a background task, changing **`ap_name_to_silence`** to the name of the ap chosen for throttling:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"                \
| grep --line-buffered  'string "ap_name_to_silence"'                   \
| sed -u -e  's/.*/killall notify-osd/g'                                \
| bash
```

Basic `Notify` structure in `dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"` is

```
    method call sender=:1.278 -> dest=:1.151 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
       string "notify-send"                          this is the app_name
       uint32 0                                      this is the replaces_id
       string ""                                     this is the app_icon
       string "test"                                 this is the summary
       string ""                                     this is the body
       array [                                       this is the actions pairs list
       ]
       array [                                       this is the hints dictionary
          dict entry(
             string "urgency"
             variant             byte 1
          )
       ]
       int32 -1                                      this is the expire_timeout
```

test silencer with these messages noting `"silenced notification"` is absent:

```
notify-send "sum airy" "ephemeral corporeal content"; sleep 5; 

gdbus call --session                                             \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                            \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                            \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                     \
                        ap_name_to_silence                       \
                        42                                       \
                        gtk-dialog-info                          \
                        "The target"                             \
                        "silenced notification"                  \
                        []                                       \
                        {}                                       \
                        5000

notify-send "augend airy" "ephemeral corporeal content - ie. white moo juice\!" 

gdbus call --session                                             \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                            \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                            \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                     \
                        my_app_name                              \
                        42                                       \
                        gtk-dialog-info                          \
                        "Summary"                                \
                        "but now it's autumny and not wintery"   \
                        []                                       \
                        {}                                       \
                        5000
```

Bookmark:
[Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56390/is-it-possible-to-block-notifyosd-for-one-application/192689#192689)