# Suppress notification when a client connects to my vino server VNC

Tags: 20.04, vnc, notification, vino

**EDIT**

If I connect via ssh, launch `dbus-monitor`, and then connect with TigerVNC, this is what I see.

```
$ dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
signal time=1650458466.197413 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.236 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.236"
signal time=1650458466.197460 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.236 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.236"
method call time=1650458500.661102 sender=:1.98 -> destination=:1.69 serial=119 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=CloseNotification
   uint32 9
method call time=1650458500.662477 sender=:1.69 -> destination=:1.49 serial=109 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=CloseNotification
   uint32 9
signal time=1650458500.664097 sender=:1.49 -> destination=(null destination) serial=10204 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=NotificationClosed
   uint32 9
   uint32 3
signal time=1650458500.665577 sender=:1.69 -> destination=(null destination) serial=110 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=NotificationClosed
   uint32 9
   uint32 3
method call time=1650458500.673202 sender=:1.98 -> destination=:1.69 serial=120 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "GNOME Desktop Sharing"
   uint32 0
   string "preferences-desktop-remote-desktop"
   string "Another user is controlling your desktop"
   string "A user on the computer 'xxxxxxxxxx' is remotely controlling your desktop."
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "desktop-entry"
         variant             string "vino-server"
      )
   ]
   int32 5000
method call time=1650458500.678437 sender=:1.69 -> destination=:1.49 serial=113 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "GNOME Desktop Sharing"
   uint32 0
   string "preferences-desktop-remote-desktop"
   string "Another user is controlling your desktop"
   string "A user on the computer 'xxxxxxxxxx' is remotely controlling your desktop."
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "desktop-entry"
         variant             string "vino-server"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "sender-pid"
         variant             uint32 13810
      )
   ]
   int32 5000
```

**Related**

1. [Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56390/is-it-possible-to-block-notifyosd-for-one-application)
2. [Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in)
3. [How can I temporarily filter-out certain notification-bubbles coming from specific sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252036/how-can-i-temporarily-filter-out-certain-notification-bubbles-coming-from-specif)
4. https://askubuntu.com/a/194279/226614

---

I am using `vino-server` in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
When a client connects to my PC I get a notification.
I want to disable them.
The client is TigerVNC in Win 10, but I guess that is irrelevant.

I have set `org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect` to `false`.
Since setting this from the command line did not seem to alter what I see in `dconf-editor` (at least immediately, I didn't tinker further with this), I also set this in `dconf-editor`, and rebooted.

I have this.
I don't know where else to look for.

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['vnc']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect false
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

How can I disable these notifications?

It seems unlikely to do that at the vino level (even if there is a setting for that, apparently!).
Perhaps the handling of notifications has some type of filtering.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep notif
ii  gir1.2-notify-0.7:amd64            0.7.9-1ubuntu2         amd64    sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Introspection files)
ii  libevent-2.1-7:amd64               2.1.11-stable-1        amd64    Asynchronous event notification library
ii  libkf5notifications-data           5.68.0-0ubuntu1        all      Framework for desktop notifications
ii  libkf5notifications5:amd64         5.68.0-0ubuntu1        amd64    Framework for desktop notifications
ii  libnotify-bin                      0.7.9-1ubuntu2         amd64    sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Utilities)
ii  libnotify4:amd64                   0.7.9-1ubuntu2         amd64    sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon
ii  libstartup-notification0:amd64     0.12-6                 amd64    library for program launch feedback (shared library)
ii  libuv1:amd64                       1.34.2-1ubuntu1.3      amd64    asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
ii  update-notifier                    3.192.30.10            amd64    Daemon which notifies about package updates
ii  update-notifier-common             3.192.30.10            all      Files shared between update-notifier and other packages
ii  vlc-plugin-notify:amd64            3.0.9.2-1              amd64    LibNotify plugin for VLC
```

What I *could* do is disable notifications globally with *Do Not Disturb*, and it effectively worked for my case, but that applies to any notification.

[image]

Comment: Hello. It may not have effect but you are behind in updates. You show 20.04.3 a fully up to date system is 20.04.4

Comment: @David - I know. But that likely does not matter here.