# How to disable notification from network-manager

Tags: network-manager, notification

Can i disable all libnotify related notification from Network Manager ? 'Edit Connection' dialog doesn't help out

Comment: seem neither of this (answers below) works for ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### 12.10 - Dconf

Run these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications "true"
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications "true"
```

Or open dconf-editor and scroll down to `org` ▸ `gnome` ▸ `nm-applet` and check `disable-connected-notifications` and `disable-disconnected-notifications` settings there.

[image: DConf]

---

### 11.10 and 12.04 - Gconf

Gconf-editor lets you edit the network manager notifications.

To alter these settings, install `gconf-editor` from the software-center.

Scroll to `/ ▸ apps  ▸ nm-applet`  and check `disable-connected-notifications` and `disable-disconnected-notifications` settings there. Check the attached image for clarifications.

[image: gconf editor]

Comment: Alternatively in cmdline: `gconftool -s /apps/nm-applet/disable-disconnected-notifications --type=bool true` (and same for `disable-connected-notifications`) (@joker feel free to merge into answer)

Comment: @Caesium You should probably create a new answer to this question :)

Comment: Another one that bothers me is when it warns about connections available... to mute that up just write this: gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet suppress-wireless-networks-available "true"

Comment: Command line (gsettings) still works for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can confirm, the `gsettings ...` commands work on ArchLinux (2023) (Kernel `6.1.8`), with `nm-applet` (`NetworkManager 1.40.12-1`) and `i3` (`4.22`)

Comment: Still works for Ubuntu 22.04!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to jokerdino's way, you can change this in commandline too:

```
gconftool -s /apps/nm-applet/disable-disconnected-notifications --type=bool true
gconftool -s /apps/nm-applet/disable-connected-notifications --type=bool true
```

To see what can be changed:

```
gconftool -R /apps/nm-applet
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers might help you with getting rid of "you are connnected" messages, but there's a bug, at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/445872 (see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/921717 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/835972 ), causing the disable-disconnected-notification setting to be ignored.

Until that's fixed, there is a workaround. Put this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/49_killall_notify`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
    ( sleep 2 ; /usr/bin/killall /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd ) &
    ( sleep 4 ; /usr/bin/killall /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd ) &
     ;;
esac
```

then `chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/49_killall_notify`. This is for Xubuntu, on regular Ubuntu I guess it would be `/usr/bin/killall notify-osd` or something like that. You might also need to tweak the sleep times.

But this is an ugly hack ;) it'd be better to see a real fix.

Answer (score 1):

unhammer is correct that disabling disconnect notifications in gconf-editor doesn't work. In regular Ubuntu you can kill the disconnect notifications with:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
```

Then kill the notify-osd process.

I guess this probably kills all notifications, not just network-related ones.

Answer (score 1):

A crude solution:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"                \
| grep --line-buffered  'string "NetworkManager"'                       \
| sed -u -e  's/.*/killall notify-osd/g'                                \
| bash
```

Caveat:
`killall notify-osd` is non-discriminating and completely wipes the notification stack of any pending messages irregardless of whether NM is the notifying agent.

An "honest" solution can be finessed but this requires that pending notifications, other than NM's, need to be reestablished while maintaining their temporal integrity. This means the chronological ordering needs to be maintained for the other notifications and the `dbus` monitored to check if the notifications' status has changed ... ie. canceled, message altered etc.

Ideally, the direct `dbus` use of

```
method void org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id)
```

to specifically target just the NM's  notifications, is unfortunately not obvious ...

ref:

- [Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in)
- [Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56390/is-it-possible-to-block-notifyosd-for-one-application/192689#192689)
- [Close button on notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd/189956#189956)

Bookmark:
[How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager/194279#194279)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ubuntu 18.10 then you can disable from gnome.

[image]

[image: go to network section then]