# How do I turn off wireless connection notifications?

Tags: notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager)

When a wireless connection is made, an indicator bubble pops up announcing the connection, and it hangs around for a little while.  How do I turn that off?

Comment: I believe your question may have been answered before:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager