# Accidentally clicked "don't show this message again" - how to reactivate?

Tags: gnome, gconf, dconf, network-manager

When Gnome 3.2 told me, there are wireless networks available, I accidentally clicked "don't show this message again".

How can I reactivate this message?

Comment: Related to the question: http://askubuntu.com/a/83110/25798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there's a GUI way to do this, but this will work:

```
gconftool --toggle /apps/nm-applet/suppress-wireless-networks-available
```

This basically edits the Gnome "registry" to toggle the value that you set when clicking that button.

Comment: right! I found out it's also possible to use `gconf-editor`. For some reason I thought gconf-editor was replaced with dconf-editor.

Comment: Yeah, some programs use dconf (especially in Gnome Shell) and some use gconf. Wish they'd make up their mind =P. Also, you were correct in using gconf-tool, though it takes longer than copy/paste that command into a terminal or Alt+F2

Comment: Does not work for me, ubuntu 15.10: `No value found for key /apps/nm-applet/suppress-wireless-networks-available`

Answer (score 1):

Editing the gnome configuration file in your home directory at `/home/<your account>/.gconf/apps/nm-applet/%gconf.xml` and change the corresponding lines to false should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf&gt;

...

<entry name="disable-connected-notifications" mtime="<some value>" type="bool" value="false"/>
<entry name="disable-disconnected-notifications" mtime="<some value>" type="bool" value="false"/>;

...

</gconf>
```

Comment: `gt;` is a mistake, right?