# Where can I find network manager's gconf key?

Tags: vpn, search, gconf, dconf

I did it again: When vpn notified me that a vpn-connection was not successful (in Gnome 3) I accidentially clicked "Don't show this notification again" (see [Accidentally clicked "don't show this message again" - how to reactivate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106004/accidentally-clicked-dont-show-this-message-again-how-to-reactivate))

Now I can't find the corresponding key in gconf and dconf.

Do you know where it is?
How can I search for keys?

Comment: I can search in `gconf` with "Ctrl+F" but not in `dconf`, in 11.04. I would expect search feature to be available also at your place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `~/.gconf/apps/nm-applet/%gconf.xml`