# List of gconf keys, in particular nm-applet

Tags: gnome, network-manager, gconf

I made the same mistake (clicking "do not show again" in NM applet) as this guy: [Where can I find network manager's gconf key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109489/where-can-i-find-network-managers-gconf-key)

The problem is that the entirety of my nm-applet/gconf.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
<entry name="stamp" mtime="1361807727" type="int" value="3"/>
</gconf>
```

So the only listed key is "stamp". I will manually add a new key "suppress-whatever: false" in gconf-editor, but I don't know the name of the key to add.

gconftool-2 --recursive-list /apps/nm-applet

only shows *existing* keys, i.e.:

stamp = 3

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Ubuntu 12.10+, nm-applet has been ported to GSettings so you can either browse the keys with dconf-editor at org.gnome.nm-applet or check out the schemas at /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/, in this case org.gnome.nm-applet.gschema.xml.

There is also a gsettings command line client, so if I have guessed the key you want correctly, it would be:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet suppress-wireless-networks-available false
```