# How do I re-enable disabled network notifications (never show again) in Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, notification

I had a popup that my wireless network had disconnected and hit the "don't show this message again" button. I actually want it to show. I can't figure out how I would reenable it. This is Unity on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I found this question/answer: 
[Where can I find a Unity configuration file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52025/where-can-i-find-a-unity-configuration-file)

It says Unity uses gconf and references 
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options

However, that answer is from July 2011 and that path does not exist in my system.

I found
/apps/conpizconfig-1/unity

but underneath that I cannot find anything about network messages.

Comment: Similar  question http://askubuntu.com/questions/106004/accidentally-clicked-dont-show-this-message-again-how-to-reactivate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications
```

if that is `true`, do a:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications false
```

Next time when you have something like this do a:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case WhateverYoureLookingFor | more
```

Comment: Thanks. I had read in another answer that Unity used gconf but in the comppiz-1 section, but I guess that is incorrect. In my particular instance it would be "disable-disconnected-notifications" and "disable-connected-notifications". In using Configuration Editor (gconf-editor), I have no clue where org.gnome.nm-applet would show up. Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Scooter: Changed!  If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Can you change the "get" as well?   Should "true" be at the end of set?

Comment: @Scooter: Oops! Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: I marked it as a correct answer, but in terms of the question, it should actually read "if that is true, do a:" and the value to set it to should be false - as I want to enable it and the setting is true for disable and false for enable. The list-recursively is a good tip.