# Can I remove the brightness tooltip?

Tags: 11.10, brightness

I don't need the tooltip because changing the brightness gives you visual feedback on its own. More importantly, the tooltip really slows down my computer - if video is playing the tooltip causes it to stutter, unlike the volume change tooltip, which doesn't slow down the computer.

Comment: Are you sure the "tooltip" causes the problem? Can you try killing notify-osd and then changing brightness? If it still stutters then you have another problem.

Comment: I killed notify-osd, but it was re-spawned as soon as I pressed the brightness keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently there is a bug filed against this on Launchpad [#461058](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/461058) to disable on screen notifications.

You can customize the appearance of notify-osd by installing a ppa described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html).

[Mark Shuttleworth has previously suggested a patch for this would be welcome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd).

Currently there is no way of achieving what you want.

Comment: @satuon - can you upvote the answer as well?, as part of the site clean up we need good answers to be voted for as well as accepted - thanks.