# Control notification display time or better close them

Tags: unity, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close button on notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd)
>   [How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications)

The Unity notifications  (notify-osd) are very much useful and nice. But It seems I can't close them after I get notified. They get blurred when I hover mouse over them, but they don't close. Which is sometimes very annoying.

I Googled about the matter and it seems, there is no way to close them until now.

Can I at least control their notification display time? *(If I can close them, that will be lot better)*. I think, It will be easy by changing some of their settings file.

Note that, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity, *specifically Unity 3D*.

Comment: I think this can help [http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html)

Comment: Closing them is a [dupe of this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd). Shortening the display duration is a [dupe of this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications).

Comment: @Samik, I am using Precise, and that link was only for 11.04 and 11.10

Comment: @AnwarShah I think it's also available for precise, have a look [here](https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/leolik?field.series_filter=precise)