# Close the notifications that hover over the current window

Tags: notify-osd

Is it possible to dismiss the notifications that hover over the current window? I've noticed that they become translucent on mouseover (but they still tend to cover part of the current window!). Is it possible to actually close these notifications so that they will be slightly less irritating?

Comment: How can I find all questions that I have not yet accepted?

Comment: Click your name at the top of the screen to view your profile. You can see all your questions there. (Or [go here](http://askubuntu.com/users/71277/anderson-green?tab=questions).) Questions in this list show the number of answers in a circle to the left. If the circle is filled in solid green, an answer has been accepted. Otherwise, there is no accepted answer. BTW, feel free to [post on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) if you have questions about how to use the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Lord of Time](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/lord-of-time) said, this is not possible at this time....well..sort of.

There is a patched NotifyOSD that will allow you to close them on click and various other customizations.

Selected out-takes from [http://www.webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html)

> The patched NotifyOSD supports the following customizations:
>
> - **close the notifications on click**

There are other options listed but that one pertains specifically to your question.

There is a lot of information on the page I linked to so I will not just copy it all here, but refer you to the page so you can read more about it and decide if it's something you want to do.

You will need to enable a custom PPA repository to install this fix. This fix actually upgrades the `libnotify-bin` so to uninstall it you will actually have to downgrade by purging the PPA to make the lower version available again.  This is easiest to do by installing [Ubuntu Tweak](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/ubuntu-tweak-07-gets-app-and-source.html).  Purging the PPA thru Ubuntu Tweak will automatically reinstall the most current official version of `libnotify` again.

Answer (score 0):

In a  terminal window, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, enter the command

```
killall notify-osd; exit
```

will do it and any pending notifications get purged too

see:

- [How do I use 'notify-send' to immediately replace an existing notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161851/how-do-i-use-notify-send-to-immediately-replace-an-existing-notification/190397#190397)
- [How to empty the queue of pending notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155877/how-to-empty-the-queue-of-pending-notifications/155881#155881)
- [How can I temporarily filter-out certain notification-bubbles coming from specific sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252036/how-can-i-temporarily-mute-all-notification-bubbles-coming-from-one-or-more-so)
- [How to empty the queue of pending notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155877/how-to-empty-the-queue-of-pending-notifications)