# filter messages to "notification area" applet

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, notification, notification-area

I need to change the way the notification area applet (not the indicator applet!) is displaying notifications. I like the old way where notifications were briefly shown on a black popup window; I can only get that behavior if I remove the notification area from the panel. However, if I do so, my pidgin icon disappears also.

On my panel, there are two icons served by the applet: pidgin icon and a mail icon with small black number showing how many notifications are there. I think it is extremely annoying to accumulate notifications such as "user is offline" or "all downloads are completed" because I have to constantly click on "Clear all notifications" button .

Is there a way to filter the notifications or otherwise configure the widget? Is there a source code for it? I couldn't find it, there seems to be no process associated with the applet.

Thank you!

PS: I'm running gnome-classic on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

A crude generic solution:

[How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager/194279#194279).

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"                \
| grep --line-buffered  'string "NetworkManager"'                       \
| sed -u -e  's/.*/killall notify-osd/g'                                \
| bash
```

Replace `string "NetworkManager"` with the desired RE to filter out messages.

To get an idea of what RE pattern match to look for run:
`dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"`
and look at the output while the notifications are popping-up.

**Caveat**:
`killall notify-osd` is non-discriminating and completely wipes the notification stack of any pending messages irregardless of whether NM is the notifying agent.

For details see:
[How can I temporarily filter-out certain notification-bubbles coming from specific sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252036/how-can-i-temporarily-mute-all-notification-bubbles-coming-from-one-or-more-so)

cross refs.:

- [How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager)
- [How to empty the queue of pending notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155877/how-to-empty-the-queue-of-pending-notifications)
- [Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56390/is-it-possible-to-block-notifyosd-for-one-application/192689#192689)
- [filter messages to "notification area" applet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298149/filter-messages-to-notification-area-apple)
- [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)